# jquery datatables server side - filter column on top

Tags: datatable, datatables

Hello I need to move on the top the filter column on my JQUERY DATATABLES 1.10.10
I have the filter column on the bottom:

```
$("dtabledID thead th").each( function () {
        var title = $(this).text();
        $(this).html( "<input type=\"text\" placeholder=\"Search "+title+"\" />" );
    } );
```

And a classic:

```
// Apply the search column filters
    table.columns().eq( 0 ).each( function ( colIdx ) {
        $( 'input', table.column( colIdx ).footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
            table
                .column( colIdx )
                .search( this.value )
                .draw();
        } );
    } );
```

My DataTables use scrollX and scroolY function...and the content ***is generate server-side***, and all work correctly ..the filter too.

I have need to move the filter on top (after or berfore) the Title (TH and THEAD)

I have try many solutions without success, for example :

**Add TD columns in THEAD**  dont work

```
<thead>
<tr><th>col1</th><th>col2</th></tr>
<tr><td>col1</td><td>col2<</td></tr>
</thead>



 $(document).ready(function() {
$('#mytable thead td').each( function () {
        var title = $('#mytable thead th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
});
$("#mytable thead input").on( 'keyup change', function () {
        table
            .column( $(this).parent().index()+':visible' )
            .search( this.value )
            .draw();
});
});
```

**CSS solution:** don't work

```
 tfoot {
    display: table-header-group;
}
```

any suggestion?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### SOLUTION

- Add extra row in `thead` for search filters with the same amount of columns.
- Use [`orderCellsTop`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/orderCellsTop) to instruct plugin to use top row for sorting.
- Use the code below to create filters and attach event handler.

```js
// Setup - add a text input to each header cell
$('#example thead tr:eq(1) th').each( function () {
    var title = $('#example thead tr:eq(0) th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();
    $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
} ); 

var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    orderCellsTop: true
});

// Apply the search
table.columns().every(function (index) {
    $('#example thead tr:eq(1) th:eq(' + index + ') input').on('keyup change', function () {
        table.column($(this).parent().index() + ':visible')
            .search(this.value)
            .draw();
    });
});
```

#### DEMO

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a6565umd/96/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: thank Gyrocode..now work..but I have another problem with save state, please see this https://jsfiddle.net/a6565umd/2/

Comment: Thats a great example .. working perfectly with responsive plug-in .

Comment: `orderCellsTop` worked well! This is the best way to instruct datatables to use the table labels for sorting instead of the filters. I had an issue where clicking in a filter input would cause the table to sort, but using this option fixed it for me.

Comment: This works fine when all columns are visible, but when we have column visibility/Buttons plugin activated, Making a hidden column visible will not show search box instead just a column header. Do we have any solution for this?