# Filter row tfoot below thead in DataTable

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables

I have a Datatable which gives huge results. Till now I've had my table in the format:

head

foot

body

But now, i have new requirements which takes up a bit more space than before..(new fields and many records), so i implemented `scrollx` and `scrolly` to my datatable. And unfortuantely it ruined my nice table format to:

head

body

< horizontal scrollbar >

foot.

How do I implement both?

I've followed countless SO answers but I always fell short because of my project requirements.
I use my footer for filtering.

**Code**:

`````
$('.table-responsive').html(response);
        $('#results_table tr td:first-child').css( 'cursor', 'pointer');
            $('#failure_summary').hide();
            removejscssfile("/static/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js", "js");
            //removejscssfile("/static/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.js","js");
            addScript("/static/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js");
            //addScript("/static/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.js");
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();                     
            table = $('#results_table').DataTable( {
                orderCellsTop: true,
                fixedHeader: {
                    header: true,
                    footer: true
                },
                "scrollY": 400,
                "scrollX": true,
                'scrollCollapse': true,
                'bDestroy': true,
                initComplete: function () {},
                'autowidth': false
            });
        ````
`````

I used the CSS:

```
tfoot {
    display: table-header-group;
}
```

This worked before I added the scrollbars. Please help in making my footer come back below head and above body.

Reference I used:

[How to place DataTables column filter on top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17629060/how-to-place-datatables-column-filter-on-top?answertab=votes#)

[jquery datatables server side - filter column on top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33822265/jquery-datatables-server-side-filter-column-on-top).

Edit:
https://jsfiddle.net/LjxeL5hu/ This was the closest in giving me a solution, but in this, the dataTable creation is in jquery while I have that in a function that was called from the success of an AJAX call. So `.onkeyUp` Did not work for me if I put that outside the function. (Table and column variable does not exist error arises).

Thanks.

Comment: can you add your code in jsfiddle to show live demonstration?

Comment: I've tried adding them, But because of noodlecode(and project security) I can't replicate in jsfiddle. I could give the jsfiddle of one close-example from their reference. 
https://jsfiddle.net/a6565umd/165/