# Column filters in jQuery datatable not working in fixed header

Tags: jquery, datatables, filtering

I'd like to use Gyrocode's [(see SO link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33822265/jquery-datatables-server-side-filter-column-on-top?rq=1) excellent example of filtering columns in a datatable.  However, I'd like the column filters to be part of a fixed header.  I've added scrollY: '50vh', to the datatable configuration and this fixes the column filters nicely. Problem is that now the column filters don't work and my limited jQuery knowledge has left me stumped!  Any ideas?
 https://jsfiddle.net/zaoz5419/

```
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.datatables.net/r/dt/dt-1.10.9/datatables.min.css'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.datatables.net/r/dt/dt-1.10.9/datatables.min.js'></script>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2011/04/25</td>
        <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>63</td>
        <td>2011/07/25</td>
        <td>$170,750</td>
    </tr>
<!-- see fiddle for extended list -->
</tbody>
```

});

.

```
$(document).ready( function () { 
// Setup - add a text input to each header cell
$('#example thead tr:eq(1) th').each( function () {
    var title = $('#example thead tr:eq(0) th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();
    $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
} ); 

var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    orderCellsTop: true,
    scrollY: '50vh',
    scrollCollapse: true,
});

// Apply the search
table.columns().every(function (index) {
    $('#example thead tr:eq(1) th:eq(' + index + ') input').on('keyup change', function () {
        table.column($(this).parent().index() + ':visible')
            .search(this.value)
            .draw();
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem is with your selector when you apply the search. Somehow when the datatable is created it doesn't have the id `example`. If you change your selector as follows it works. I'm not sure why you're losing the id when you call datatable. :

```
// Apply the search
table.columns().every(function (index) {
    $('.dataTable thead tr:eq(1) th:eq(' + index + ') input').on('keyup change', function () {
        table.column($(this).parent().index() + ':visible')
            .search(this.value)
            .draw();
    });
});
```

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zaoz5419/2/)

Comment: Wow, really well spotted, but like you, I can't work out why I'm losing the id either.  Much appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm not sure either. I tried the latest version of datatables and same result. Weird.