# Is it possible to implement individual column searching in datatable serverside?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, datatables

I have trouble when implement column filter in datatables server side. the filter column appear, but doesn't work. I have take a look at many references like below link, but still can't solved my problem.

https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html

https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/styling/col_filter.html

[jquery datatables server side - filter column on top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33822265/jquery-datatables-server-side-filter-column-on-top)

this is my code so far i have tried.

```
$('#table tfoot th').each( function (i) {
        var title = $('#table thead th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" data-index="'+i+'" />' );
    } );


    table = $('#table').DataTable({ 

        aLengthMenu: [
            [15, 25, 50, 100, 200, -1],
            [15, 25, 50, 100, 200, "All"]
          ],
          iDisplayLength: 15,
        "processing": true, 
        "serverSide": true, 
        "ordering": false,
        "searching": true,
        "scrollY": true,
        "scrollX": true,
        "order": [], 

        
        "ajax": {
            "url": "<?php echo site_url('drawing/ajax_list_welding_plan')?>",
            "type": "POST",
            "data": function ( data ) {
                data.drawing_no = $('#drawing_no_table').val();
                data.project_no = $('#project_table').val();
                data.drawing_title = $('#drawing_title_table').val();
                data.document_title = $('#document_title_table').val();
                data.client = $('#client_table').val();
            }
        },

        "columnDefs": [
            { 
                "targets": [ -1 ], 
                "orderable": false, 
            },
            { 
                "targets": [ -2 ], 
                "orderable": false, 
            },
            {
                "targets": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21], // your case first column
                "className": "text-center",
                "width": "4%"
             },
        ],

    });

    $( table.table().container() ).on( 'keyup', 'tfoot input', function () {
        table
            .column( $(this).data('index') )
            .search( this.value )
            .draw();
    } );
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can implement individual column filtering using server-side processing.

But, as with global filtering, and sorting and paging, you need to implement the logic on the server, to handle this.

Assuming you are using `"serverSide": true`, whenever you perform an action in your DataTable (such as paging, sorting, or filtering), DataTables sends an ajax request to the server, using the URL in the DataTables `ajax` option.

DataTables does this automatically for you. The request contains all the information the server needs to perform sorting, filtering, and paging.

For example, here is one such request:

```json
{
    "draw": "5",
    "columns[0][data]": "id",
    "columns[0][name]": "",
    "columns[0][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[0][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[0][search][value]": "",
    "columns[0][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[1][data]": "name",
    "columns[1][name]": "",
    "columns[1][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[1][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[1][search][value]": "",
    "columns[1][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[2][data]": "description",
    "columns[2][name]": "",
    "columns[2][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[2][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[2][search][value]": "widget",
    "columns[2][search][regex]": "false",
    "order[0][column]": "1",
    "order[0][dir]": "asc",
    "start": "30",
    "length": "10",
    "search[value]": "",
    "search[regex]": "false"
}
```

This request is asking the server to return 10 rows of data, starting at row index 30 (where the first row is actually row index 0):

```
"start": "30",
"length": "10",
```

This represents "page 3" of the table's data, with 10 rows per page.

And it is asking the data to be sorted on column 1 in ascending order:

```
"order[0][column]": "1",
"order[0][dir]": "asc",
```

(You obviously need to sort the data first, before you can know which are the correct 10 rows you need to send to DataTables.)

The following line indicates that there is no global search term:

```
"search[value]": "",
```

But these next lines indicates that there is a column-based search term for column index 2 (the 3rd column in the displayed table):

```
"columns[2][search][value]": "widget",
"columns[2][search][regex]": "false",
```

The search term for that column is `widget` - and the term is to be interpreted as a literal value (not a regular expression).

So that is the information your server needs to use to build the correct set of 10 rows, to be sent back to DataTables: First the server needs to sort and filter the entire data set - and then it needs to return the 10 rows needed for "page 3" of the results.

Normally, the request fields for column search values are blank. But when you add search fields to the footer of your DataTable, then these fields can be populated.

The documentation for the request sent from DataTables to the server is [here](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side). You can also see the documentation for the reply here, too.

There are various ways to add individual column filtering to your table (as you have seen!). If you follow [this example](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html), you can then enhance the example to use server-side processing - and you will see the `columns[n][search][value]` fields being populated.

I recommend you do this, and get it working, before integrating that solution into your specific environment.

You can use your browser's console (F12) to see the network XHR requests (and responses), to verify that the data is being sent to the server correctly.

Of course it is your server's (i.e. your PHP code's) responsibility to capture and read the DataTables request on the server, and then provide the server-side logic to use the request information correctly.

Comment: Hi @andrewjames thanks for reply. it does do request, but not returning the correct data. I have check the console, the ajax request correct, but my table not filtering.

Comment: Did you write the code to perform the server-side filtering? You have to provide that.  DataTables will not do the filtering for you.