# How to support client-side ordering for Datatable in sever-side processing

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, datatables

I have a java project that needs to display a huge data in a data table with the option to sort data from the client-side (In the browser).

I used server-side processing to perform the code and the data was displayed well. But the problem is that the ordering (sorting column by clicking on the column name) does not work from the client-side.

How can I solve this problem?

Here is the code of my data table:

```
RecycleBinTable = $("#RecycleBinDataTable").DataTable({
                    ajax: function (data, callback, settings) {
                        GetMainParentWindow(window).showLoading();

                        var recycleBinUrl = document.getElementById("RecycleBinURL").value;
                        var isAdmin = getQuerystringByURL(recycleBinUrl, "admin");

                        if (isAdmin == '')
                            isAdmin = false;

                        if (RecycleBinTable) {
                            pageSize = RecycleBinTable.page.len();
                            startIndex = RecycleBinTable.page.info().page * pageSize;
                        }

                        var url = AppSettings.RecycleBinUrl + "FillGrid?startIndex=" + startIndex +
                            "&pageSize=" + pageSize;

                        $.ajax({
                            dataType: "json",
                            type: "POST",
                            url: url,
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            data: JSON.stringify({ isAdmin: isAdmin }),
                            processData: false,
                            cache: false,
                            headers: {
                                "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + loggedInUser.Token
                            }
                        }).done(function (result) {

                            callback({
                                recordsFiltered: result.recordsFiltered,
                                recordsTotal: result.recordsTotal,
                                data: result.data
                            });

                        }).fail(function () {
                            GetMainParentWindow(window).alertMessage(resources_Warning, resources_Error, resources_Ok);
                        }).always(function () {
                            GetMainParentWindow(window).hideLoading();
                        });
                    },
                    serverSide: true,
                    processing: true,
                    ordering: true,
                    bPaginate: true,
                    pageLength: pageSize,
                    bJQueryUI: true,
                    pagingType: "input",
                    language: {
                        "sSearch": " " + resources_Search + " ",
                        "zeroRecords": resources_NoMatchingRecordsFound,
                        "info": resources_Of + " _TOTAL_ " + resources_PagingItems,
                        "infoFiltered": '',
                        "sLengthMenu": " _MENU_ ",
                        "infoEmpty": resources_ShowingZeroEntries,
                        "sEmptyTable": resources_NoDataInTable,
                        oPaginate: {
                            "sFirst": "",
                            "sLast": "",
                            "sNext": "",
                            "sPrevious": ""
                        }
                    },
                    dom: 'C<"clear">RZfrtpli',
                    columns: columns,
                    scrollX: true,
                    scrollCollapse: false,
                    scrollY: "300px",
                    bAutoWidth: false,
                    deferRender: true,
                    bLengthChange: true,
                    lengthMenu: [10, 25, 50, 75, 100, 250, 500],
                    searching: false,
                    responsive: true,
                    createdRow: function (row, data, index) {
                        $('td', row).eq(1).html(imgRendererRecycleBin(data));
                    },
                    columnDefs: [
                        {
                            'targets': 0,
                            'searchable': false,
                            'orderable': false,
                            'className': 'dt-body-center checkBoxWidth',
                            'render': function (data, type, full, meta) {
                                return '<input type="checkbox">';
                            }
                        },
                    {
                        "autoWidth": false,
                        "bAutoWidth": false,
                        'targets': 1,
                        'orderable': false,
                        'render': function (data, type, row, meta) {
                            return '</img>'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        'targets': 3,
                        'render': function (data) {
                            return '<span style="whitespace=nowrap">' + data + '</span>'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "autoWidth": false,
                        "bAutoWidth": false,
                        'targets': 5,
                        'orderable': true,
                        'sortable': true,
                        'visible': ((getQuerystringByURL($("#RecycleBinURL").val(), "admin", "")) ? true : false),
                        'render': function (data, type, row, meta) {
                            return data;
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "autoWidth": false,
                        "bAutoWidth": false,
                        'targets': 6,
                        'render': function (data, type, row, meta) {
                            return dateRendererRecycleBin(data);
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "autoWidth": false,
                        "bAutoWidth": false,
                        'targets': -2,
                        'render': function (data, type, row, meta) {
                            return convertBytesToKb(data);
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "autoWidth": false,
                        "bAutoWidth": false,
                        'searchable': false,
                        'orderable': false,
                        'targets': -1,
                        'render': function (data, type, row, meta) {
                            return "<a href=\"#\" onclick='RestoreItem()'><i title='" + resources_Restore + "' class=\"SVGContainer StaticPosition\">" + GetMainParentWindow(window).resourceicon_Restore + "</i></a>";
                        }
                    }],
                });
```

Comment: Client-side sorting is disabled when you use server-side processing (the same as client-side paging and filtering are also disabled). For all of these actions, you are normally expected to handle them in your server-side code. Is there a reason why you cannot do that here?

Comment: @andrewJames thank u for the clarification. Yes I will try to handle the ordering from the server-side but I don't know how can I send the clicked column name and its current order to the server-side to apply the sorting from the server

Comment: Take a look at the [official documentation](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side), where this is described. You can also take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65039190/12567365) which focuses on filtering (searching), but also shows an actual example for sorting: `"order[0][column]": "1", "order[0][dir]": "asc"`. For more background, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67959632/12567365). The key point is: This data is _automatically_ sent from the DataTable to the server whenever the user performs a paging, sorting, or filtering action on the table.